# Android - Drawable, apply a color filter to a specific color

Tags: android, colors, paint, android-drawable

Can I apply a color filter to a drawable but specifying the color I do want to tint?

Example: my result drawable is a composition of two squares, one square is red (#FF0000) and the other square is blue (#0000FF). I want to have a function that returns a Drawable where i pass the existing color I do want to change and the new color I do want to apply.

Code example of how I see it:

```
private Drawable switchColorOnDrawable(Drawable mySquares, int existingColor, int replaceColor){
    //mySquare -> represents my image
    //existingColor -> the color I do want to switch
    //replaceColor -> the new color that should be replaced

    //TODO -> ???

    return mySquares;
}
```

**Edit:** Minimum SDK version = 17

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can! Its only a matter of how! As I prefer easier methods, I would go for `EffectFactory` or the Adobe creative cloud SDK, both are good, yet distinct in their own ways. Check out :

- [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html)
- [this](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/)

Comment: How can I work with EffectFactory? Which method would you recommend, by the documentation list, it seems that nothing fits to my needs